# Sort Array of Strings by index

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, swift4

I have an array of strings as follows:

```
["\(title)|\(time)|\(length)|\(event)"]

["test1|00:24.42|SC Meters|50 Free", "test2|00:25.52|SC Yards|100 Free", "test3|00:26.73|SC Yards|100 Free", "test4|00:27.34|SC Yards|100 Free"]
```

I am using this to sort by title:

```
selectedSwimmerTimes = selectedSwimmerTimes.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
```

Can I sort the array of strings by a start and stop index? So can I use the above sorting method except instead of sorting the strings based on the first letter alphabetically, sort the strings by index 6 through 13.

I have tried other methods such as splitting into variables and iterating through a dictionary but the other code for the app needs this to be an array of strings.

Comment: This would probably be better to create a struct called Swimmer with variables name, time, distance, etc. Instead of having a string contain all the information.

Comment: @Martheli And that would allow them to stay grouped? Say I switched index 1 and 2 that would mean I would have to switch the other 3 variables too

Comment: Yes it will allow them to stay grouped and you can sort them much easier than this especially its a single string, you will have to split them but its a lot of work to do for nothing, as @Martheli said use struct or class and then sort them easily.

Comment: @AaoIi is it possible to sort a string array by start index and end index of each string instead of sorting the whole strings?

Comment: Your example has ` "test1|00:24.42|SC Meters|50 Free"` so you mean the first index of string is t and last is e then its te for first string, do you want to sort it this way ? if not can you please give me just a little example and i will try to help you :)

Comment: @AaoIi so I have these multiple strings in the array can I sort the array by index 6 through 13? so when its sorting the array instead of looking at the whole string it sorts it only based on the information between the first two | and  |. Example: iterate through each string in the array and look at the 00:00.00 times and sort it that way instead of the whole string

Comment: I already did it that it will sort depending on the data between the first | and the second |. thats what you mean by index 6 and 13. do you want the data to be Ascending or Descending, you can just change the sort by function from .orderedAscending to .orderedDescending? unless I really didn't get your question.

Comment: @AaoIi I cant use the multiple variables due to the information being displayed in a tableview. I need to keep it an array of strings due to all the other code in the app depends on that.

Comment: So you will need to sort it but keep the array the way it is? you don't want to use struct, just sort it and keep it as is right ?

Comment: You should structure your data, make your structure CustomStringConvertible and implement the description property. Then you can sort your struct using  any property

Comment: @AaoIi yes just like this "selectedSwimmerTimes = selectedSwimmerTimes.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }" except intead of sorting the whole string its just index 6 through 13

Comment: Btw this is not a code writing service. You should show what you have tried and the issues you are facing

Comment: @LeoDabus I have tried splitting it into variables and iterating through a dictionary. I simply cannot find a way to use the .sorted property with a given index

Comment: @WillMays Edit your question and post your attempts explaining the issues you are facing

Comment: This is crazy, you really need to use structs or classes. Don't just glue all your data together into a single string, it'll be so cumbersome to work with!

Comment: @Alexander yes indeed !

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for the clarification. @AaoIi has provided an answer that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all its not the best practice at all to not use struct or class and its totally not recommended just to glue everything in a single string as @WillMays and @Alexander they mentioned but here is away.**

Ok lets say you have a struct here with name Data:

```
struct Data {

    var name : String
    var time : String
    var distance : String
    var price : String

}
```

Define sortType enum:

```
enum sortType {
    case time
    case distance
}
```

You got this method which is going to convert the the array of strings and split each one into struct of type Data sorted and then convert it back to string array and return it:

```
func splitAndParseArrayIntoStruct(type:sortType)->[String]{

    let soruceArray : [String] = ["test1|00:24.42|SC Meters|50 Free", "test2|00:25.52|SC Yards|100 Free", "test3|00:26.73|SC Yards|100 Free", "test4|00:27.34|SC Yards|100 Free"]
    var dataArray = [Data]()

    // convert the data into struct

    for data in soruceArray {

        let splitedData  = data.components(separatedBy: "|")

        // make sure you have these indices
        let dataObject = Data(name: splitedData[0], time: splitedData[1], distance: splitedData[2], price: splitedData[3])
        dataArray.append(dataObject)

    }

    // sort the data array
    let sortedDataArray = type == .time ? dataArray.sorted(by: { $0.time.compare($1.time) == .orderedAscending }) : dataArray.sorted(by: { $0.distance.compare($1.distance) == .orderedAscending })

    var newSourceArray = [String]()

    // recreate the normal array

    for data in sortedDataArray {

        newSourceArray.append("\(data.name)|\(data.time)|\(data.distance)|\(data.price)")

    }

    return newSourceArray

}
```

And the last thing to do is to call the following line which will split and sort and return the new array.

```
    let dataArray = self.splitAndParseArrayIntoStruct(type: .time)
```

Comment: But once I sort the time the index of name and distance have to stay the same as time

Comment: @WillMays since you updated your answer of what you tried as requested,  i have updated my answer.

Comment: @Aaoli This worked! Is there anyway to have the dataObject as a parameter so I can call splitAndSortSoruceArray(time) so it will sort the time or splitAndSortSoruceArray(distance)

Comment: I would strong advise against initializing struct members to `""`. There is very rare a valid reason to default to empty strings.